# Get the results from system() and store in variable?

Tags: php, unrar

I'm running this script:

```
$output = "unrar x -y ".$number.".rar /bundle/";
echo "<pre>";
system($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Which is outputting

> Extracting 
>   /var/www/html/bundle/Compressed_file_test/lgc-m.r29
>     0%  1%  2%  OK

I want to figure out the folder name which it is, in this case "Compressed_file_test". Is there a way i can get that information ?

Answer (score 3):

You want to get the info back intop a variable? You add a 2nd parameter. However, system only returns the last line, `shell_exec` returns everything

```
$result = shell_exec($output);
echo $result;
```

[Documentation on shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/shell_exec)

---

If you want the value:

```
 $dir = substr($output, strpos($output,"/",22), strrpos($output,"/"));
 // or via regex:
 preg_match('/\/(.*?) ?/', $output, $matches);
 $dir = $matches[4];
 // or if you know its the last:
 $dir = end($matches);
```

That is a simple example, if you get more complex results, you are going to have to change this (you might want to explode on newlines to get induvidual lines)

Comment: Yeah, just noticed only the last line gets returned. Changed my answer

Comment: The second parameter doesn't do what you think it does. See the docs: "*If the return_var argument is present, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.*"

Comment: I know, I allready changed my answer to a function which does

Comment: Your answer still has the "*You want can a 2nd parameter*" bit. It doesn't make any sense. Please fix all the typos in your answer (for example: "Shell?exec" should be `shell_exec`, `stubst` should be `substr` etc)

Comment: Should the $dir = substr ? I changed to that but still dosen't give me the actual dir.

Comment: it was just an example, you can use a regex or other functions to get the value you need. Note the 22, that could be 4, I dont know if offset is number of matchers, or offset into string

Comment: This worked in the end: preg_match('#/bundle/(.*?)/#', $output, $matches); thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like that:

```
$command = "unrar x -y ".$number.".rar /bundle/";
$output = shell_exec($command);
$output = explode(PHP_EOL, $output);
$output = $output[0];
    
preg_match_all('/\/[A-Za-z0-9_]+/', $output,  $matches);
echo $matches[1][count($matches[1])-2];
```

Used functions:

- [exec()](https://www.php.net/function.exec)
- [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/preg_match)

Comment: Im getting `Warning: preg_match(): Empty regular expression in /var/www/html/bundle/unrar.php on line 14`

Comment: $output and the regex are the other way around, regex goes first

Comment: Getting this now: Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found in /var/www/html/bundle/unrar.php on line 14

Comment: You are allowed to do some research yourself. Add a slasg before the last single quote in the regex

Comment: Yeah i did that but it just came back with "All" assumed i did something wrong. It isn't displaying the progress now it just displays the last line "All Ok" then $matches contains "All"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the program output in your code, consider [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead of system().

```
 $command = "unrar x -y $number.rar /bundle/";
 exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

Also, make sure `$number` doesn't contain any special characters (like `;`), or escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$output = "unrar x -y ".$number.".rar /bundle/";
echo "<pre>";
system($output,$result);
preg_match(/\/(.*)/, $result, $path);
echo basename($path[0]);
echo "</pre>";
```